# Extremum of functional of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-optimization

consider functional $E$ defined by

$$E[z]=\int F(x,z(x))dx$$

where $F$ is a complex-valued nonlinear function.

How can we find the function $z(x)$ so that

$$G=|E|^2=EE^*=\iint F(x_1,z(x_1))F^*(x_2,z(x_2))dx_1dx_2$$

takes its maximum?

Comment: What do you mean by "be extremum?" Also, have you tried anything yourself - you will likely get much better answers if you tell us what you have tried already.

Comment: @JoeTait 
I tried to define $G$ as a new functional and then use Euler-Lagrange Equation, but I'm confused! 
In $G=\iint F(x_1,z(x_1))F^*(x_2,z(x_2))dx_1 dx_2$ the function $z$ is one time a function of $x_1$ and another time is function of $x_2$, and on the other hand $z$ must have a unique behavior. this situation is true for function $F$, too.
by "Extermum", I mean maximum.This problem is a real-world physical one, so There is a function $z$ that can make $G$ maximum.

Comment: Is $x$ real valued, or complex?  What is the integral over?  (If $x$ is real-valued, you must have fixed endpoints, right?)

Comment: @JeffSnider yes. $x$ is real and endpoints are fixed $\int_a^b$

Comment: Do you want an analytic solution, or is a numerical approximation sufficient?

Comment: @JeffSnider Is there any analytic solution? I prefer analytic solution but if there is not any, approximation is the alternative.

Comment: Whether an analytic solution exists depends on your $F$.  I will try to write an answer for the numerical approach sometime today.

Comment: @JeffSnider i'll be waiting to hearing from you.

Answer (score 0):

Find $z$ maximizing $$G(z):=\iint_\Omega F\big(x_1,z(x_1)\big) F^*\big(x_2,z(x_2)\big) \,dx_1 \,dx_2$$
We are given $F$ -- I assume it is twice differentiable, but there are methods (mentioned below) in nonlinear optimization that work for functions which are not.  I assume there are no restrictions on $z$; if it must be continuous you will select a different numerical approximation.  I assume $\Omega$ to be the box $[a,b]\times[a,b]\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Let $z$ be a map from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$.  Pick a discretization for $x$ of size $n$, e.g., divide $[a,b]$ into $n$ segments of equal length.  Their length will be $\ell=\frac{b-a}{n}$ so that their center points are $x_{k}=a+(k-\frac{1}{2})\ell$.  We approximate the integral by the midpoint rule -- there are vastly better methods but this is suitable for a first attempt.  This gives us the approximation
$$G_n(z)=\ell^2\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n F\big(x_j,z(x_j)\big)F^*\big(x_k,z(x_k)\big)$$
We now pick a discretized approximation to $z$ by defining (where $i=\sqrt{-1}$): $$z_k=a_k+i b_k=z(x_k)$$ and assuming $z$ is constant on the whole interval of length $\ell$ surrounding $x_k$.  Now $z$ is just a sequence of complex values and we have
$$G_n(z)=\ell^2\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n F\big(x_j,a_j+ib_j\big)F^*\big(x_k,a_k+ib_k\big).$$
Our goal is to pick the values of $a_k$ and $b_k$ for each $k\in\{1,2,\dotsc,n\}$ maximizing $G_n$.

There are a wide variety of nonlinear techniques to solve this unconstrained problem -- Newton's method ought to work well if you have two derivatives and a reasonable initial guess.  Your goal is to find the stationary points where the derivative is zero, and check they are a maximum by looking at the second derivative.  If you don't have derivatives then you can use something like the compass method.

And for what it's worth, in my opinion the hardest part will be correctly writing the derivatives of the function.